# KB4486563 broke Internet Explorer URLs

Tags: iis

Our product runs exclusively in Internet Explore -- yes I know -- I know ...
The problem is that when the code was written the html looks like this

```
<img src="images\image.gif" WIDTH="72" HEIGHT="24">
```

Since this update we are now getting access denied in the vbscript/javascript code that tries to access the DOM -- or just the images not displaying at all

Does anyone know of a setting in IIS to allow this url to still work after this KB has been installed.

I know the work around is to change all the code to be correct with a forward slash.

I tried to add a registry setting to hoping that the problem was with:  Adds top-level domain support to HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Preload for Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11.  But that didn't help

Any ideas?

Comment: This update also broke some old pages in Compatibility view, also some smartcard readers don't work... If anyone has some relevant info or links, please post.

Comment: Thank for your question and @Marcel van Waijen answer below solved it to me

Answer (score 8):

we had the same issue where IE showed an Access Denied error to the following line of javascript after installing KB4486563 for Windows 7 64-bit:

document.getElementById(textboxID).src = "images\yes.png"

After changing the backslashes to forward-slashes like this:

document.getElementById(textboxID).src = "./images/yes.png"

everything was working fine again.

So try to change the backslash to a forwardslash to see if that fixes it.

Comment: This worked for me as well, God bless you and curse Microsoft

Comment: Thanks -- I did eventually do that -- its just that we had about 75-100 customers down because of it.

Comment: This worked for me as well, even though MS has released the patch (kb4491113) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft listed it as a [Known Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486563/windows-7-update-kb4486563). Their workaround is:

> Change the backslash (\) to a forward slash (/) in the relative path of the image element.
>
> Or
>
> Change the relative path to the full URI path.
>
> Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update in an upcoming release.

**update (20.02.2019):**

Microsoft released [KB4486565](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486565/windows-7-update-kb4486565) that should solve this.